# Handling large XML files in Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to Android development and want to create a Google map app. I have to use 2 large XML files with geo data (latlons), 1 is 2mb and the other 8 mb big.

What is the fastest way to access and parse this data? Is it maybe beter to store this into a database? A webservice is not a good idea I think, because everytime the app will start I have to load 10 mb... And that will process very slow I guess...

Has anybody some good advice?

Thanks!

Comment: A webservice **is** a good idea. Having that data loaded into your Android application would suck due to the size of the download and potentially slower load times.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the whole data in the server and access it from device using webservices. Better to go for SAX parser as the data is too large. If possible better to implement search functionality from server end or to implement pagination from server end.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create some kind of meta data to go along with the large xml file. This meta data can point to specific parts of the large xml file. And each small part can be a dom object instead of a sax parser.

I suggest using sax, creating a summary of the data you need in some kind of hashtable (simple key value pairs) and using it. May be using SharedPreferences for data that does not change.

Also you need to think on how / what data will be used and how frequently. May be you can keep a producer consumer architecture, where a thread prepares the data for use, and the consumer uses it when its ready on a notify or something.

You need to think from 3 angles

- Not too much serial processing
- Not redoing what you have already parsed
- Parsing using the right quantum of data. Infact think of dom for small parts to make your design easier to start with.

And I dont recommend DOM for the entire tree. You need to use a combination of SAX and DOM.

First get it working, and then record response/performance delays and work your way up to improve it from the worst to best.